# Garbled text on startup

Tags: boot, grub, startup, display

I'm having an issue with my Ubuntu Server 16.04 installation. I have it running on a Zotac Z-Box CI23 Nano. It installed fine, but on its first boot all I had was a blank screen. I edited `/etc/default/grub` and changed `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"`

This let me see the startup, but the text is all garbled white blocks:

[image: screenshot]

I first thought it might be a bad cable, so I switched cables with no change. I changed monitors with no effect. I switched to a TV using HDMI with no effect.

Any ideas would appreciated.

Comment: I would reinstall, but seem a incompability with your box.

Comment: Compare http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/289979/5132 , which has a similar appearance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this figured out. At first I thought it was bad hardware so I RMA'd the machine. The same exact thing was happening on the replacement. So I spent a few hours fiddling with grub settings. This is what ended up working for this machine:

in `/etc/default/grub`:

Comment out `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet"` entirely.
Uncomment `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`

Uncomment `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` I set it to `GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x800` because that's the monitor I'm using's default.

Save it then `sudo update-grub` and reboot and it is showing as expected. Only the combination of those three changes seem to make it work for me, but YMMV.