# Weird wrong encoding displayed at systemd booting

Tags: boot, systemd

After GRUB loads the linux image `linux-vmdisk` or similar, and systemd has loaded, I found the screen displays the systemd boot process steps with a wrong and weird encoding. But after a few seconds and some systemd services have loaded, the screen refreshes, and the display is then correct.

My system is "Arch Linux" with latest update.
And systemd version is:

```
systemd 232
+PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK -SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
```

EDIT: here is my dmesg log https://gist.github.com/stardiviner/dfbeb58a7afb2a10dab1e9d51ff34686

I want to know are there related bugs?
If I can't find out why, then tell me how to debug this issue?

Comment: Can you identify the part in the `dmesg` where the encoding gets messed up?

Comment: It messed up after GRUB, and loading initramfs, until a specific systemd unit started. It is quick so I can't remember it. I will updated here after reboot to take a clearly look.

Answer (score 2):

The strange characters at boot might be due to a wrong GRUB configuration.
Try these solutions that involve changes to `/etc/default/grub`. After each change, remember to update GRUB (`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` or `update-grub`) and then reboot to test the change.

1) Add these lines:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=<mode>,1024x768x32,auto
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

where `<mode>` is the resolution of your screen as `<width>x<height>x<depth>`, see line above for an example.
 
Note that this mode must be supported by your graphic card; to get a list of supported modes, run

```
sudo hwinfo --framebuffer
```

[More info here.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Setting_the_framebuffer_resolution)

2) If this still doesn't work, try to add a parameter `vga=` (note: deprecated) to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash vga=792"
```

3) If still these solutions doesn't work, try this (taken from [this previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304771/garbled-text-on-startup/305104#305104)):

Comment out the line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

Add the lines

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=<width>x<height>
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

where `<width>x<height>` is the native resolution of your monitor.

Comment: This answer is very detailed. can you describe the reason of why caused wrong characters?

Comment: I tried all of your methods. none of them works. But thanks still.

Comment: Have you tried changing the settings in `/etc/vconsole.conf`?

Comment: No, have not touched it.

Comment: Try to change the `vconsole.font=` parameter in it. (I don't know how you find the available fonts in Arch Linux; I'll try to find this info and add it to the post later).

Comment: I tried to set vconsole font with `FONT=Lat2-Terminus16` and re-generate initirial ramdisk with `makeinitcpio -p linux`. restart system cause all systemd output wrong characters, failed `LightDM`.

Answer (score 0):

If by wrong or weird encoding you mean something that looks like this:

[image: Text in terminal appear like symbols]

Then it may be a result of some startup scripts or command outputting binary data to your console, and...

> In such scenario some particular byte sequences may be interpreted by
> your terminal emulator as control sequences or so, they will affect
> its later behavior.

as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1336953/1168619).

Since the issue sounds like it resolves itself, if there is still a desire to try and determine what may be causing the issue, you may want to check any startup configurations you have set (i.e. in `cron` or `rc.local`) in addition to checking `systemd`

For posterity, `systemd` related processes reviews can be checked using (with sudo)

```
systemctl status


# or alternatively
systemctl --failed

# or to check all  the services available
systemctl list-unit-files --type=service
```

Whereas possibly related directories may include (as reference for both Arch & non-Arch users):

- `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`
- `/etc/systemd/system/`
- `/etc/rc.local/`
- (As aforementioned for cron) running `crontab -e`
- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `~/.profile`

For ease of reference:

- [Arch Linux Systemd Wiki Page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd)
- [Reference Article for Autostarting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Autostarting#On_Xorg_startup) items not already mentioned for review
- [Suspected Related Issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1336947/weird-characters-appearing-in-the-console) and the origin of the previously linked answer cited as a possible explanation